# Can't load assembly from GAC but it loads from program's folder

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, gac

I'm developing a C# application with .NET Framework 4.0, Entity Framework 6.1.3 and Sqlite 1.0.96.0.

I have an assembly that use `SQLite`, `MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common`, installed on GAC (`System.Data.SQLite` is also installed on GAC).

I have two errors:

> 'Entity Framework used the default instance DbConfiguration before the
>   type was detected' SQLiteConfiguration '. An instance of
>   'SQLiteConfiguration' should be set at the beginning of the
>   application before using any feature or Entity Framework must be
>   registered in the configuration file of the application. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information. '

To fix this, I have add the following in `App.config`:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common.SQLiteConfiguration, MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common">
```

But, after adding this to `App.config` the program it doesn't load it from GAC.

I have to copy the same dll into EXEC folder to load it and run the program.

I think this is not a version number problem or the dll has a bad format, because I'm using the same dll in GAC.

I have also added this to `App.config`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common" publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.0" newVersion="1.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

But I have to copy the dll to application's folder.

Any idea?

Comment: In the native equivalent of the GAC, assemblies are versioned and have a so called 'strong' name that includes a hash - whereas when private (in the same folder as the app) assemblies are loaded just the assembly name is used. Perhaps a similar principal applies here and you are not specifying the correct version of the assembly so it cannot load from the GAC? Just a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading assemblies from the GAC  needs the fully qualified assembly name. For example;

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common.SQLiteConfiguration, MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common, Version=1.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ABCD1234567890">
```

Comment: Thanks. It works! Where did you find that info? I've been searching a lot I have only found this way: `<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common.SQLiteConfiguration, MyCompany.Data.Sqlite.Common">` and nothing about GAC.

Comment: GAC can store multiple versions of assemblies, so to load one, you need to explicitly state which one by adding version, key, etc. Learnt from experience in software build and release management :)